# Enabled Trusted Host Settings in settings.php keep showing up as not enabled

Tags: 8, configuration

I just installed Drupal 8.0.1. I have changed the Trusted Host Settings on my website. But in the error report it is still saying that "Trusted Host Settings NOT ENABLED".

The lines are:

```
$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = array(
  '^artosphere\.eu$',
  '^www\.artosphere\.eu$',
  '^localhost$',
);
```

Tried with and without `'^localhost$`.
I have seen that this question has been asked on other sites. And once here. But I cannot find a solution anywhere.

The site is on a shared host.

Comment: This is not a required setting so I don't understand why there should be such error + the patterns are correct. I think your issue lies somewhere else.